# Remove top line in Recharts SimpleAreaChart

Tags: recharts

I'm using Recharts 2.0.9 and I was able to style Area chart nearly how it should looks like, but the problem is when I set axisLine to false there is still a short line and it looks strange.
Also one additional top line is added to Y axis. Maybe somebody would know how I can hide those short lines and top line?

[image]

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={124}>
  <AreaChart
    data={data}
    margin={{
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    }}>
    <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
    <YAxis
      type="number"
      domain={[60, 90]}
      ticks={[60, 70, 80, 90]}
      height={111}
      interval={0}
      tick={{ fontSize: 11 }}
      width={20}
      padding={{ top: 10 }}
      axisLine={false}
      tickLine={false}
    />
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These short lines in Recharts are called ticks. You can remove them using the `tickLine` axis property:

```js
<XAxis tickLine={false} />
<YAxis tickLine={false} />
```

Without seeing the source code, it's hard to tell why the upper horizontal line appears. It is possible that the paddings for the axis are specified via the `padding` property, or Recharts incorrectly defines the boundaries, here you can try to set the boundaries via the `domain` property:

```js
<YAxis type="number" domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} />
```

See https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#domain

Comment: Thanks @Wild Zyzop tickLine did the trick. 

As for top line I added some code to my question, maybe it would help with investigation.

Comment: @Ardneh I think the problem with top line is in the `padding={{ top: 10 }}` property in the `<YAxis />`

Comment: most probably, but without padding top is cut off, I added image to the post

Comment: @Ardneh This is probably because you specified the height for both the chart and the Y-axis. Try removing the height for the axis. If you need to set the fields around the chart, it is better to do it in the AreaChart margin property.